# Formula of a polynomial with n roots

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, summation, formal-proofs

I have been trying to solve this proof:

[image]

My observations were:

- The polynomial could be rewritten in factored form: (x-c1)(x-c2)....(x-cn)
- The RHS could be rewritten as the sum of each c-term
- Taking the common denominator of the RHS would lead p'(c1)*....p'(cn)*the factored form of the polynomial

But I wasn't able to proceed any further than these observations.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does the polynomial have degree $n$?

Comment: Where does it say that the polynomial is monic? Your factorization assumes this.

Comment: It only says n distinct roots

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider some polynomials $p, q$ such that $c$ is *not* a zero of either of them, and. Then by partial fractions we know:

$\begin{equation*}
\frac{p(x)}{q(x) (x - c)}
   = \frac{A}{x - c} + \text{ other junk}
\end{equation*}$

The remaining stuff has no denominators divisible by $x - c$.
We are after $A$. A nice trick that gets it almost for free is to multiply by $x - c$ and have $x \to c$ in the result. You get:

$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to c} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}
   &= A 
      + \lim_{x \to c} (\text{other junk}) (x - c) \\
\frac{p(c)}{q(c)}
   &= A
\end{align*}$

For your particular case, it is clear that the sum of fractions of this form gives a fraction with denominator $p(x)$. You can write:

$\begin{align*}
p(x)
  &= a \prod_{1 \le i \le n} (x - c_i) \\
\frac{1}{p(x)}
  &= \sum_{1 \le i \le n} \frac{A_i}{x - c_i}
\end{align*}$

where you'd compute using the above trick
(remember $p(c_i) = 0$):

$\begin{align*}
  A_i
    &= \lim_{x \to c_i} \frac{x - c_i}{p(x)} \\
    &= \lim_{x \to c_i}
         \frac{x - c_i}{p(x) - p(c_i)} \\
    &= \frac{1}{p'(c_i)}
\end{align*}$

The last is by the definition of the derivative (and $p'(c_i) \ne 0$, by how $p(x)$ is written).

Comment: I am kind of confused about how you used the trick to go from the product to the summation.

Comment: Taking natural log might be helpful.